# Robot Framework - Keyword to do in case the leadtime is not respected

Tags: robotframework

I'm stuck on something in my Robot Framework project. When I hit a button from the 1st page after the login is done, another tab is opened, however, sometimes, the new window is not loaded and the code (robotframework) keep waiting for an answer.

To avoid getting an error when this situation happens, I want to solve it while the code still running, I want to know if there is any keyword that applies an action in case something is not done within a given lead time. In my case it would be to close the new window and repeat the previous step (hit the button from the first page again), therefore, it would be 2 actions in case the actions fails (lead time).

I have tried to use the keyword `Run Keyword and Return Status`, in my case the status would be false, however, since my code is kept waiting for an answer, the status is always `True`, therefore, it does not work for me.

[image]

I have read that there is a keyword named `Run Keyword If Timeout Occurred` however, it can be only used on Teardown`, therefore, I also don't know if it can applied.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Pictures aren't searchable, copyable, and visually impaired people can't read them at all.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are trying to compare `Boolean` and `String`.
it's should be boolean and boolean `run Keyword if   ${status}==False`.

Comment: When the button is pressed,  a new tab will be opened anyway, when the page cannot be loaded, a message from the website is raised, informing it will be necessary to login again and to press the button "OK", therefore, the status will only appears (LOG), after the user press the button "OK", that is the problem, because until the user does not hit the button, the code will not show the status. I need to take an action based on time, so the robot framework can understand if the next step is taking too long, it means the error message on the website has appeared